# Rank system in R, recursive function

Tags: r, function, recursion, rank

I really don't have idea what I'm looking for, if a loop, recursive function or maybe something different.

This is my toy dataset:

```
ID1  S1   S2   S3   
1    10   20   30   
2    20   30   40
1    50   60   70
3    20   40   50
1    10   30   10 
2    40   20   20
```

`toy$OLD_RANK` = find previous row with same ID1 and copy NEW RANK of that row. If no row with same ID1 give assigned value (10 in this example)

`toy$NEW_RANK` = OLD_RANK + S1+S2+S3

expected result:

```
ID1  S1   S2   S3   OLD_RANK    NEW_RANK
1    10   20   30      10        70  
2    20   30   40      10        100
1    50   60   70      70        250
3    20   40   50      10        120
1    10   30   10      280       330
2    40   20   20      100       180
```

## dataframe for R as requested:

```
toy <- matrix(c(1,10,20,30,2,20,30,40,1,50,60,70,3,20,40,50,1,10,30,10,2,40,20,20),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(toy) <- c("ID1","S1","S2","S3")
toy <- as.data.frame(database )
```

Comment: Hi @Mirko, first of all, it could be helpful to have your data to copy and paste in R, rather then rewrite them. Back to your question, it seems that `OLD_RANK` and `NEW_RANK` are strongly binded, one defines the other: which is the start in your idea?

Comment: I've update the thread with the code.
My idea is to build a custom rank between two players. If no data is available before, give an assigned value.

Comment: According to your description, the third row of `OLD_RANK` should be `70` and not `100`, and then `NEW_RANK` will be `250` instead of `280`